# React ImmutableJS - ShouldComponentUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutable.js

Parent component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Child } from './Child';

const testObject = {
  test: {
    one: false,
    two: false,
    three: false,
  },
};

export class Parent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      test: testObject.test,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Child test={ this.state.test } />
    )
}
```

Child component:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

export class Child extends Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    return nextProps.test !== this.props.test;
  }

  render() {
    console.log('hey! i\'m rendering!!');
    return (
       <div>Child</div>
    );
  }
}

Child.propTypes = {
  test: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

Question:
Right now, it doesn't work. shouldComponentUpdate still re-renders when let's say test.one becomes true. I read the doc on immutablejs and on react doc but I still don't understand. It should be easy for you guys, can someone help?

Comment: How do you modify test?

Comment: I have been updating state like this: const newState = update(this.state, { test: { one: { $set: true } } }); this.setState(newState); I meant to simplify but forgot to add setState. I read your post below, thanks for your help. Can't I use immutablejs to see if value of object changed? That's what I read in doc but don't know how it works in my case...

Comment: You can use [shallow-equals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shallowequal) to verify if object values changed

Comment: Thanks, shallow-equals works perfectly. I have a separate question if you could answer for me. Right now, my child component won't re-render when the props passed changes from parent, but when other states in parent changes that weren't passed as props to child, it re-renders. It's obvious it should do this, but is there an easy way to stop it from re-rendering? I don't want to pass unnecessary props to child...

Comment: Nevermind, I just added return false :)

Answer (score 1):

`testObject` is not an immutable. Sure it cannot be replaced by another object: `testObject = anotherTestObject` is forbidden, but `one`, `two` or `three` can  be modified: `testObject.one = true` will be ok. ImmutableJS provides mecanismes to forbid `testObject` value modification.

Calling SetState will create a new `this.state.test` and as a result, `nextProps.test !== this.props.test` always resturns true.

Comment: Thanks, I was confused by your previous post. Thanks for breaking it down for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your component re-renders because the evaluation `nextProps.test !== this.props.test` will always return `true` because neither the value or type ever changes.

You seem to only change the property values of `one`, `two` and `three` of your `test` object. The problem here is that you're trying to evaluate the properties of one object to another, and this cannot be done with (strict) comparison operators (such as `==` or `===`).

One way of solving this is converting your objects to JSON for the comparison:

```
return JSON.stringify(nextProps.test) !== JSON.stringify(this.props.test);
```

Another solution would be to compare each property one-by-one:

```
for(let key in this.props.test) {
  if(!(key in nextProps.test) || this.props.test[key] !== nextProps.test[key]) {
    return true; //the current property didn't evaluate - component should update 
  }
}
for(var key in nextProps.test) {
  if(!(key in this.props.test) || nextProps.test[key] !== this.props.test[key]) {
    return true; //the current property didn't evaluate - component should update 
  }
}
return false; //the objects are equal - component shouldn't update
```

**Edit:** Damien Leroux correctly points out that your `testObject` is immutable since you've declared it as a constant. You probably want to change that.